# Can not print out elements in dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

I have the following code, I pass the same pointer to both functions but I can only print out array elements in `addNewValue` function.

I do the same for `printArray` but the program stop and does not print anything.

What should I do to fix this problem, I have searched on stackoverflow but it seems like I can't find the answer for my problem.

```
int main()
{
    int *array = NULL;
    int value;
    int length = 0;
    int *lengthP = &length;

    printf("Enter new value");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    addNewValue(array, value, lengthP);

    printArray(array, lengthP);

    return 0;
}

void printArray(int* array, int* lengthP)
{
    int i = 0;
    int length = *lengthP;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *array[i]);
    }
}

void addNewValue(int* array, int value, int* lengthP)
{   
    *lengthP = *lengthP + 1;
    int length = *lengthP;

    array = realloc(array, length * sizeof(int));

    if(array == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }

    array[length - 1] = value;

    printf("%d", array[0]); 
}
```

Comment: you are not changing the `array` pointer in your main function.

Comment: @Osiris but i pass the pointer to addNewValue function, and i add new element to the array, so i think it should change the array pointer in main too?

Comment: No the pointer is passed by value, like everything in C. You change the copy of the pointer which was created at the function call.

Comment: debugger; breakpoint; examine variables; find null-pointer dereference

Comment: @Osiris So my  array pointer points to NULL at first, and if i want to change it with realloc, the only i can do it is to have another pointer, points to my array pointer and pass it to the function?

Comment: @ThuanNguyen Yes, or you return the new array pointer. You also do not need to create a pointer you can just call the function with `&var` as argument.

Comment: It is almost always confusing to use the same name for a parameter within a function and in the calling code. The `array` inside `printfArray` is a copy of the `array` in main, and the `array` inside `addnewValue` is a different copy. If you get in the habit of using different names, it can help you avoid the mistake of thinking you're looking at the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever your function `addNewValue(array, value, lengthP)` does, it will never change the value the pointer `array` passed to it. Note that `array` in main and `array` in `addNewValue` are two different variables; the value of the former (i.e. a "memory address") is copied into the value of the latter, and `addNewValue` is changing a copy, not the original pointer value from `main`. Hence, `array` will always be `NULL`. Hence, you'll dereference NULL and yield undefined behaviour.

Change

```
void addNewValue(int* array, int value, int* lengthP)
```

to

```
void addNewValue(int** array, int value, int* lengthP)
```

and call it using

```
addNewValue(&array, value, lengthP)
```

Adapt the logic in `addNewValue` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't modify the array of `main` (and that allocated in `addNewValue` is leaked BTW).

```
int main() {
    int *array = NULL;
    int value = 42;
    int length = 0;
    int *lengthP = &length;
    addNewValue(&array, value, lengthP);
    printArray(array, lengthP);
}

void addNewValue(int** array, int value, int* lengthP) {   
    *lengthP = *lengthP + 1;
    int length = *lengthP;

    *array = realloc(*array, length * sizeof(int));

    if(*array == NULL) { /* ... */ }

    (*array)[length - 1] = value;
}
```

Comment: Or you could pass the pointer by reference, `int *&array`

Comment: @Martin Cook: is this possible in C?

Comment: @StephanLechner No it is not.

Comment: Apologies, yes, that applies to c++